# Getting exception while accessing sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I am trying to access sqlite database in my app and getting this exception:

```
12-27 11:32:12.760: E/Exception:(746): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable Exception occured in ContactListOfNumbersForWhichRuleIsAlreadySpecified() of DatabaseHandlerRule.java
```

I am using this code:

```
public ArrayList<String> ContactListOfNumbersForWhichRuleIsAlreadySpecified(DatabaseHandlerRule Activity) 
    {
        ContactRule contact = null;
        Cursor cursor =  null;
        SQLiteDatabase db =  null;
        ArrayList<String> contactList =  null;
        try
        {
            contactList = new ArrayList<String>();

            //      SQLiteActivity1.ReadingAllContactsRule(SplashActivity.s_dbRule);

            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE "+KEY_NAME+" !='"
            +"abcde#$%&*()@#$%"+"'"+" AND "+KEY_PH_NO+"!='"+"abcde#$%&*()@#$%"+"'"+" AND "+KEY_DATE+" ='"+"0"+"'";

            db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            if (!db.isOpen()) {
                db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
                        "/data/data/com.velosys.smsManager/databases/rulesManager",
                        null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            }

            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    contact = new ContactRule();
                    contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                    contact.setFolderName(cursor.getString(3));
                    contact.setParentFolderAddress(cursor.getString(4));
                    contact.setTime(cursor.getLong(5));
                    contact.setDate(cursor.getLong(6));
                    // Adding contact to list
                    contactList.add(contact.getName());
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            else if(!cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                Log.e("Message: ","Rule is not specified for even a single number in database");
                return contactList;             
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception: ",e+" Exception occured in ContactListOfNumbersForWhichRuleIsAlreadySpecified() of DatabaseHandlerRule.java");
        }
        finally
        {   
            if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                cursor.close(); 
            if(db != null && db.isOpen())
                db.close();
        }
        return contactList;
    }
```

I have searched for the reasons behind this exception but nothing implies to my case:

1. I am not trying to write but read the database.Hence no question arises here about concurrency.
2. I am using instance of Database helper class in `db = this.getReadableDatabase();`
3. I am closing database properly each and everytime i open it.

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Its strange.After removing finally and putting the code without finallly block,everything is working fine.Can anyone please tell me the reason behind this?

```
          //finally
            {   
                if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                    cursor.close(); 
                if(db != null && db.isOpen())
                    db.close();
            }
```

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: Can you tell at which line you are getting this error.?

Comment: I can't say because while debugging,i am not able to produce the error.Everything is working fine while debugging.

Comment: You can if you use e.printStackTrace()

Comment: then how could you see the exception as you mentioned above.?

Comment: Please check the edit of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove finally block. in that you have close db and cursor so it this error comes.

Comment: I am supposed to close the cursor and database after completion of my work.Is not it?If i am closing them in finally clause then what is the problem?Can you please tell me?

Comment: in that you have close same db and cursor on the file DatabaseHandlerRule.java

Comment: @VatsalShah please check the edit and please put some light on reason behind it.

Comment: in finally block everytime cursor and db will be close and open thats why. instead of that completing in finally. after while loop complete close it.

Comment: @VatsalShah: Appreciated.!:)

Answer (score 0):

In the statement `db = this.getReadableDatabase();`, I'm not sure of what context you are using. So declare a global context like `Context context = this;` then call that statement as `db = context.getReadableDatabase();`

Comment: Using this i am using the context of database open helper class i.e DatabaseHandlerRule. this = DatabaseHandlerRule.this;

Comment: I think the method I suggested is more direct. Please try it out and say. Because I'm not familiar with your method of referencing :(

Answer (score 0):

Its strange.After removing finally and putting the code without finallly block,everything is working fine.Can anyone please tell me the reason behind this?

```
  //finally
            {   
                if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                    cursor.close(); 
                if(db != null && db.isOpen())
                    db.close();
            }
```