# SQlite Database: Unable to find context

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-context

Apparently there is some problem with the context and in the following line as I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. I think something is wrong with the context. Also when I"m trying to open and close database from two activities it's throwing `CannotOpenORCloseDatabase` Error. Please help.

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Any idea why? Or it'd be great if someone could suggest a workaround.

```
public static final String EXT_CATEGORY = "category";

public static final String EXT_URL = "url";

private String tableName = DBHelper.tableName;

private SQLiteDatabase MyDb;

private int category;
Cursor c = null;

public static final String EXT_POS = "position";
private String url;
private int position;
WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() called");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    openAndQueryDatabase();

}

private void openAndQueryDatabase() {

    position = 1;
    category = 0;
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() called 3");
    try {

        DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(getBaseContext());
        MyDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        c = MyDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName
                + " where Category =" + category + "AND Position ="
                + position, null);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() called 4");
        // url = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Image"));
        url = "www.google.com";
        Log.v(url, " URL in Recipe ");
    } catch (SQLiteException se) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Could not create or Open the database");
    }
```

Comment: try to use either  this or just getApplicationContext() and then check

Comment: Post the code of your database helper class as well.

Comment: `public DBHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DBName, null, version);
  currentContext = context;
  DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
  createDatabase();
`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your DBHelper as a static instance (singleton) to ensure that only one DBHelper exist at any given time.

```
 public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    private static DBHelper mInstance = null;

    public static DBHelper getInstance(Context activityContext) {

    // Get the application context from the activityContext to prevent leak
    if (mInstance == null) {
      mInstance = new DBHelper (activityContext.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
  }

  /**
   * Private, use the static method "DBHelper.getInstance(Context)" instead.
   */
  private DBHelper (Context applicationContext) {
    super(applicationContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```

To open the SQLiteDatabase use:

```
SQLiteDatabase mDataBase = DBHelper.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
```

and to close it

```
mDataBase.close();
```

Comment: DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(getBaseContext());
        MyDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  The context is working but says unable to open or close the database.

Comment: `E/SQLiteDatabase(1025): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
12-27 14:48:11.450: E/SQLiteDatabase(1025):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
12-27 14:48:11.450: E/SQLiteDatabase(1025):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
12-27 14:48:11.450: E/SQLiteDatabase(1025):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
12-27 14:48:11.450: E/SQLiteDatabase(1025):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:962)`

Comment: @LilYoda see my updated answer for opening and closing the DB

Comment: @LilYoda use: SQLiteDatabase MyDb = DBHelper.getInstance(this).getWritableDatabase(); , and use "this" instead of "getBaseContext()" or "getApplicationContext()", the DBHElper.getInstance(this) method will handle the getApplicationContext for you.

Comment: @hsigmond- I've closed the DB but problem s with opening it! But that issue I came here for resolved thanks. I'll debug a li'l more. :) Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

use constructor for this... While calling the DB class pass context as the parameter. like below.

```
    public class MyDB {

   private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public MyDB(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
db = new DbHelper(this.getContext());
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using, `DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());`

Instead you should use,

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

**Edit-**

Try using

```
MyDb = getApplicationContext().getWritableDatabase();
```

instead of

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());

MyDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Also try removing the `finally()` block as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14050185/1626878).

Comment: OK will try and get back. Thanks. :)

Comment: The above part doesn't work. I used without finally but still unable to open or close the database. Attaching the logcat and editing my code in the question.

Comment: You have already accepted the answer. so what's the issue now.?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21754/discussion-between-lilyoda-and-sahil-mahajan-mj)

Comment: Ooh no worries. I'll try to debug a li'l more. The issue I came here for is resolved.

Comment: @LilYoda: It would be helpfull for future visitors, if you could post how your issue solved.