# SQLiteConnection, database was leaked, after fast trigger update

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-database

My error log :

```
    2019-11-28 11:46:59.415 13936-13936/com.example.thongapps E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 35803 of [605907e73a]
2019-11-28 11:46:59.415 13936-13936/com.example.thongapps E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:35803: (24) open(/data/user/0/com.example.thongapps/databases/dbThong) - 
2019-11-28 11:46:59.421 13936-13936/com.example.thongapps E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.example.thongapps/databases/dbThong'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:210)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:194)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:200)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:192)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:864)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:849)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:724)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:295)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
        at com.example.thongapps.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:86)
        at com.example.thongapps.CustomeAdapter.removeDBItem(CustomeAdapter.java:448)
        at com.example.thongapps.CustomeAdapter.access$100(CustomeAdapter.java:23)
        at com.example.thongapps.CustomeAdapter$1.afterTextChanged(CustomeAdapter.java:114)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9429)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5434)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5281)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:117)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5238)
        at com.example.thongapps.CustomeAdapter.getView(CustomeAdapter.java:84)
```

The Strange thing is, when i do it in slow way, all is fine, but when i do it in faster way to editText, database leak and cant open. My Trigger function is to delete when the user set 0/remove anything in editText(editText inside listview, multiple editText in row and more than 1 row) then the record is removed in database. When i add no any problem(using button), but for `delete` cz some reason i need to update manually each update in row. And there is case, when record not yet to save and user change to 0/remove data inside editText but this already in my exception.

So my question is why when i doing CRUD data in other function is fine, but in function remove editText got stuck. Only when i remove/set to 0(trigger to remove record) with fast, but when i doing it in slow way everything is alright.

just make little clear my problem almost same like :
[Getting error while executing getwritabledatabase() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595300/getting-error-while-executing-getwritabledatabase-in-android)

So how i can init the db ? is something wrong with my db,

```
    private Context mContext;
    SQLiteDatabase db;        

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context ){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION );
        mContext = context;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (dInstance == null) {
            dInstance = new DatabaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return dInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + i + " to "
                        + i1 + ", which will destroy all old data");

        db.execSQL(tableDBVersion.UPGRADE_TABLE_DBVERSION);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(tableDBVersion.CREATE_TABLE_DBVERSION);
        db.execSQL(tableDBVersion.SEED_TABLE_DBVERSION);
    }
```

Using [Getting "Failed to open database" error when copying a sqlite database from assets In Android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377370/getting-failed-to-open-database-error-when-copying-a-sqlite-database-from-asse), still got same error. Idk if it correct way to implement to my code :

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context ){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION );
    mContext = context;
    if(!checkDataBase()){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File databasePath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
    return databasePath.exists();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Failed to open database" error when copying a sqlite database from assets In Android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377370/getting-failed-to-open-database-error-when-copying-a-sqlite-database-from-asse)

Comment: Problem is in `db = this.getWritableDatabase();` line . create a method like `public SQLiteDatabase  getDatabase(){db = this.getWritableDatabase();}`.

Comment: i recommend you to use the room api with viewmodel. It will get rid most boiler plate codes and hopefully solve your error.

Comment: still same error @ρяσѕρєяK, mycode :     `public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(){
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }`

Comment: wait checking,, @Sree

Comment: @Sree, is it right with my code ?

Comment: @frestoinc, sry, idk what u mean, is it using web service ? or other,,

Comment: checkDataBase()  is it retun ture ?

Comment: it's always true, never false.. and still error.. idk maybe in upper logcat, cz it's trigger a lot of log..

Comment: @BudiMulyo u can just search for android room or android mvvm

Comment: ok, just look little, it's like customeAdapter ya.. ok, noted. i'll try it after this..